# Sorting an array with multiple elements

Tags: java, string, list, sorting, date

I am making a to-do list in java for a class project. In the jList i display a date and a string that represent a date and what needs to be done on that day. I would also like to be able to sort these events by the dates on them, so the tasks that are due sooner appear first. I know how to sort a list of dates using bubble sort, but I do not know how to apply this to my list because each item contains a date AND a string. This is the code I have so far. Does anyone know how I will be able to sort the dates in order and keep the strings attached to their dates. Thanks.

```
public class ToDoListManager {

    final int maxitems = 20;
    int items = 0;
    String[] toDoList = new String[20];
    Date[] Dates = new Date[20];

    String addItem(String toDo, Date date) {
        if (items == maxitems) {
            return ("No more Space");
        } else if (toDo.equalsIgnoreCase("") || (toDo == null) || (date == null)) {
            return ("All fields required");
        } else if (items < maxitems) {
            Dates[items] = date;
            SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            toDoList[items] = "On " + dt1.format(date) + " " + toDo;
            items = items + 1;
            return (toDo + " Was Added to the List");
        }
        return null;
    }

    void Order(Date[] dates) {
        Date temp;
        boolean fixed = false;
        while (fixed == false) {
            fixed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < dates.length - 1; i++) {
                if (dates[i].before(dates[i + 1])) {
                    temp = dates[i + 1];
                    dates[i + 1] = dates[i];
                    dates[i] = temp;
                    fixed = false;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(dates);

    }

    String[] getItems() {
        String[] displayList = new String[items];
        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            displayList[i] = toDoList[i];

        }

        return displayList;

    }
}
```

Comment: consider starting by creating an object that represent your task, that contains both the date and the string.

Comment: Do not use [parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). Define a `ToDo` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention JList in the question, thus I assume that is where you want to see the sorted TODOs. Here's one possible way to do that:

JList is backed by a [`ListModel<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) instance. That is a generic class that can contain a list of instances of `E`. So a possible way to wire it together is to:

- Create a class that represents a an item in the todo list (class ToDo, that has the fields that contain e.g. the date and the toDo text).
- Define one or more comparators of the ToDo instances - e.g. one based on date, other on text, whatever you need.
- Populate a List (or another collection) with your ToDo instances and sort it using one of your comparators.
- Create a ListModel implementation backed by your list and set that to the JList component. The ListModel implementation can be e.g. an extension of [AbstractListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireContentsChanged(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)). Also see an [example of sorted ListModel implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SortedListModelsortableJList.htm).
- To display the ToDos in a meaningful way in the List, create a toString() implementation on your ToDo class (JList will call that to get a string representation of your object), or [supply your own ListCellRenderer to the JList instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html).
- If you need to re-sort, make sure your ListModel implementation correctly [notifies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireContentsChanged(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) the JList each time it changes the order.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a SortedMap of Date->String>?

Comment: This is the way to go

Comment: Why not use a class rather than [parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, as mentioned by Michael, is to have an object. That would store the variables you want, date and String. If you in the future want to add another variable you can easily just add this to the object, without editing the list you store the objects in.

```
public class Todo {

private Date date;
private String info;

public Todo(Date date, String info){
    this.date = date;
    this.info = info;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}
public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}
}
```

Comment: [Objects should be immutable](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/09/objects-should-be-immutable.html).  There is no reason for the setters.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly how I would structure your application. I have left out the `order` and `getItems` methods for brevity.

```
public class ToDoListManager {

    private static class ToDo
    {
        public final String text;
        public final Date   date;
        public ToDo(String text, Date date)
        {
            this.text = text;
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

    final int maxItems = 20;
    final List<ToDo> todos = new LinkedList<>();

    String addItem(String text, Date date) {
        if (todos.size() == maxItems) {
            return ("No more Space");
        } else if (text == null || text.equalsIgnoreCase("") || date == null) {
            return ("All fields required");
        } else if (todos.size() < maxItems) {

            final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            text = "On " + format.format(date) + " " + text;

            todos.add(new ToDo(text, date));

            return (text + " Was Added to the List");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can see things become much simpler to work with once you ditch the primitive arrays in favour of Collections, and you start using classes.

---

Now to answer your question: rather than implement your own sort, use [`Collections.sort(todos)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-).

In order to sort your list appropriately, you will need `ToDo` to implement [`Comparable<ToDo>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). I'll leave this up to you to research and implement.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. The trouble I have now is that I am unsure how to get the jList to display objects of the new class ToDo.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `JList`s but if you need a primitive array (i.e. ToDo[]) then you can call `todos.toArray()`.

Comment: No, i use the jLists setListData method which requires a string array (String[]). Unsure how to get the list to display this class as it seems to only want to display string arrays.

Comment: If you edit the code where the `JList` is created into your question I'll take a look.

Comment: This was all I could find. Not sure if it is what you are looking for.  jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();